# PRISM WPF How to change view in region using event?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I am creating my first wpf application MVVM using Prism.
My applications looks like:
[MainScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAAc7.png)

I have no problems with navigation using delagete commands from buttons
with _regionManager.RequestNavigate.

Unfortunatly it doesn't work when I want to change Red View using UsingEventAggregator.

```
        _ea = ea;
        _ea.GetEvent<GTM1Event>().Subscribe(ChangeView);
```

EventAggregator works correct, its change also values of Orange View variables and make           regionmanager.RequestNavigate but it doesnt change red View.

How should it be done?

Comment: You might be in background thread or something.. Try `_ea.GetEvent<GTM1Event>().Subscribe(ChangeView, ThreadOption.UIThread);`

Comment: @MuhammadSulaiman Thank you. It works :-). You are a lifesaver. I tried a lot of stupid things before I decided to ask the internet. And the solution was so "simple". I would never have thought about it ...
Writing an application without much knowledge, it's not easy. 
Probaly when i finaly done i will have to rewrite almost everything to make it more correct.

Answer (score 0):

You might be in background thread.. try

```
_ea.GetEvent<GTM1Event>().Subscribe(ChangeView, ThreadOption.UIThread);
```